# How to delete an environment label from a deleted Twitter environment?

Tags: api, twitter, label, environment, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to integrate a Dialogflow (V2) chatbot with Twitter, but in the Twitter integration modal on Dialogflow I received the error 'Bot was not started' (which doesn't really tell me why).

I tried to recreate the integration using Dialogflow's migration documentation: https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/twitter. In the documentation it mentions "Note: The environment must be named "dev". This is a restriction of the beta webhook API.". However I can't use the same "dev" label anymore on Twitter because it was previously used by the deleted dev environment (my first try)...

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there's a couple things going on here. To start, you shouldn't need to use "dev" as the environment name anymore. This has recent changed and been opened up, we just need to update the docs.

The "Bot was not started" message sounds like it's referring to starting the bot in the Twitter integration screen in Dialogflow.

Go to Integrations > Twitter and enter all of the information for your bot. Then click the START button at the bottom of that screen.